# code igniter hmvc templates not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

I have this templates folder in my new hmvc project that I am setting up.

For my controllers

Template.php codes

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Template extends MX_Controller{

    function view(){

        $this->load->view('one_view');
    }
}

?>
```

one_view.php

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

When I go to my browser and type:

```
localhost/ci_hmvc/templates/view
```

it always says that 404 Page Not Found. No matter what tutorial I watch its almost the same code and I copied every code they use but it doesnt work.

P.S: I am using htaccess so theres no index.php in my url.

Comment: localhost/ci_hmvc/template/view correct url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
localhost/ci_hmvc/template/view
```

Your controller and file name is `Template` and `Template.php` not `Templates`

**Side Note:**

Or if you still want to use as templates than add route for this controller as:

```
$route['templates'] = "template";
```

Second solution is that, change your file and controller name as `templates`.

Comment: localhost/ci_hmvc/template/view is not working. i have tried it already.

Comment: i tried changing it all to templates and it worked. thanks.

Comment: @kev_m: yes maybe it conflict with others class .

Comment: @kev_m: anyway congrats friend.

Comment: @kev_m if u think this answer solve yur problem accept this otherwise people think u r still looking for solution